# Sphinx - Minimal theme, no JS

Tags: themes, python-sphinx

I'm trying to get working a very minimal theme for Sphinx. My primary objective with Sphinx is to use it to share manuals or sets of instructions (including code snippets) with colleagues and students.

My interest in it started some time ago, when following a course on Udemy by Colt Steele, I was fascinated by the documentation he shared as part of the course. The output is clean, very portable and easy to share.

The folder structure is quite minimal, like this one as an example:

```
.
├── .buildinfo
├── _images
│ ├── cards.gif
│ └── jokes.png
├── _static
│ ├── graphviz.css
│ ├── handouts-sphinx.css
│ ├── my.css
│ └── pygments.css
└── index.html
```

So, just the html file plus the indispensable css and media. No js.

My output, however, no matter how little the content, is a lot bigger after running `make html`.

I’m guessing it is so due to the presence of the built in search and navigation functionalities (which I’d like to know how to eliminate!) but nonetheless really a lot of files:

```
├── _sources
│ └── index.rst.txt
├── _static
│ ├── basic.css
│ ├── check-solid.svg
│ ├── clipboard.min.js
│ ├── copy-button.svg
│ ├── copybutton.css
│ ├── copybutton.js
│ ├── copybutton_funcs.js
│ ├── doctools.js
│ ├── documentation_options.js
│ ├── file.png
│ ├── jquery-3.5.1.js
│ ├── jquery.js
│ ├── language_data.js
│ ├── minus.png
│ ├── plus.png
│ ├── pygments.css
│ ├── searchtools.js
│ ├── sphinx_press_theme.css
│ ├── theme.css
│ ├── theme.js
│ ├── underscore-1.13.1.js
│ └── underscore.js
├── genindex.html
├── index.html
├── objects.inv
└── search.html
```

So my question finally is:

How can I produce a theme in order to get a lean build like the one by Colt Steele with just the one html file and the css/images?

I only need the basic anchor navigation within that sole html file, no search, no `prev` or `next` pages.

How can I achieve such a build?

Here's a screenshot of the html file from the first tree to illustrate how simple it is:

[image]

Comment: You do not mention whether you followed the docs at https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/theming.html

Comment: Hi Steve, and thank you. Yes I followed it to the best of my understanding and also tried to adapt existing themes to my needs. Regrettably I invariably get a much larger build, such as the one described in my second tree, including jquery and a lot of files. I'd really love to know how to have a minimal output (just navigation on the only html file) and no js whatsoever (as the first tree pasted above).

Comment: Do you know how Jinja2 template language works? It is what Sphinx uses. All templates inherit from the the Basic theme, which is why you get all that extra stuff, unless you throw all that out the window and create a theme as a Python package that you install. This is not my idea of a good time.

Comment: Ha, yeah Steve, I know what you mean about a good time! Yes, I've worked quite a bit with Django, so I know Jinja templating. Thing is that there is perhaps a more automated way for what I want: basically to stripe the basic template from all unneeded code and have a bare build like the one on my first tree. I'll paste a screenshot of the render of that html file on my original question, maybe it helps visualising what I have in mind.

Comment: I would suggest you browse through the [gallery of available Sphinx themes](https://sphinx-themes.org/). Maybe one of them does what you want out of the box?

Comment: Yeah I’ve checked them before coming here. Regrettably all of them include search and nav and so they all bundle all the js…